# php list files in directory and save to disk

Tags: javascript, php

I want to list the files in "archives/" and write the decoded array to disk (file name = "archives/events.txt") But what I have doesn't create that file.

xhr.send(data); // gives: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

```
function LISTevents () {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("POST", "json-events.php");
 xhr.onload = function () {
 console.log(this.response);
 };
 xhr.send(data);
 return false;
}
```

**json-events.php**

```
<?php
// create list of events files in archives/* on server

$files1 = scandir('archives');

file_put_contents('archives/events.txt', print_r($files1, true));

?>
```

Comment: (1) Seeing `.txt.txt` in comments but `.txt` in code? (2) Your fopen takes a literal so dont know why it does. (3) Such mistakes must mean there is other carelessness else where

Comment: It was a cut and paste error from the actual.code. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Ok, granted. BUT `$temp = json_decode($arrFiles);` ... arrFiles *is* an array and not a string, so why are you trying to decode it? You also never init `$arrFiles` so where does it come from; it's not global because you never declare it as such?

Comment: Basically your code (wherever you got it from) is riddled with logical errors. But of the type of misunderstanding of the programming language (PHP).

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* I'll answer this directly to be fair. Your **json-events.php** has critical logical errors. Not syntax, but the code itself is flawed. `$arrFiles[]` could be derived from an "include" and may work fine (no telling since you don't post the dependency in your question). But this line *$temp = json_decode($arrFiles);* is attempting to decode a *string* to a PHP object, but *$arrFiles* is not a string, proof on the latter is you use append `[]` on it treating it as an array.

Comment: Ok. So a quick edit you think would solve this. Your edited replacement `$arrFiles = $entry->getFilename();` is buggy (logically) because it makes `$arrFiles` *not* an array, and just the last string assignment in that loop. FYI

Comment: A rule of thumb that a coding instructor once told me was "test your code after _every line you write_" because the more lines that you write without testing the more nonsensical the errors become, and the more you'll wind up having to rewrite. Your PHP code will have failed at _line 1_, and generated visibly incorrect output for several others.

Comment: I appreciate your methods. Since the php code is janky, I  changed the php to scandir and file_put_contents but "archives/events.txt"  is still not created. No console error message. If that file can be created I'll php include("events.txt") in a js array and iterate to remove the entries that don't match the desired format of "????-??-??.txt".

Comment: Gee, you spel gud!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function list_contents($dir, $suffix) {
 $contents = array();
 $dir = realpath($dir);
 
 if (is_dir($dir)) {
 $files = scandir($dir);
 
 foreach ($files as $file) {
 if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'events.txt') {
 if (substr($file, -strlen($suffix)) == $suffix) {
 $contents[] = $file;
 }
 }
 }
 
 foreach ($contents as $key => $item) {
 if (strlen($item) != 14) {
 unset($contents[$key]);}
} 

 foreach ($contents as $key => $item) {
 if (substr($item,0,1) != "2") {
 unset($contents[$key]);}
} 

 }

 $contents_json = json_encode($contents);
 file_put_contents($dir . '/events.txt', $contents_json);
 
}
list_contents('archives','.txt');
?>
```